# Does Flask map JSON Array object to a Python string?

Tags: arrays, json, string, flask

In my Flask server I am receiving a JSON-encoded parameter which is being sent via an HTTP POST from the client application.

Here is an example of what the JSON object looks like.  For simplicity, I have kept only the first 2 entries, but the full object contains many more such entries.

[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "start": 7.85,
    "end": 9.813,
    "text": "Θέλω να",
    "words": [
      "Θέλω",
      "να"
    ],
    "isBeingEditedByUser": false,
    "translatedText": "I want to"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "start": 9.898,
    "end": 13.055,
    "text": "Από κάτι το πήραν πολύ άσχημα ο οπαδός του Ολυμπιακού",
    "words": [
      "Από",
      "κάτι",
      "το",
      "πήραν",
      "πολύ",
      "άσχημα",
      "ο",
      "οπαδός",
      "του",
      "Ολυμπιακού"
    ],
    "isBeingEditedByUser": false,
    "translatedText": "Something very bad for Olympiacos fan"
  }
]

My understanding is that this JSON structure corresponds to an Array (in Javascript) or a List in Python.  In this case, it is an array containing two elements, where each element is itself an object.
However, when I try to use the object on the Flask side, it seems that it has been mapped to a string (rather than a List).   Is this normal behavior?  I have not been able to find any documentation which states that this is the normal mapping.  I would have expected the JSON object to be mapped to a Python List object instead, but this is not happening.

I know that I can use python.loads() myself to convert the string into the appropriate List structure, but I did not expect to have to do this and want to make sure that I am not misunderstanding something here.

Here is a snippet of code which shows the relevant portion in my Flask function:

```
 @app.route('/update_SRT_file', methods=['POST'])
 def update_SRT_file():   

 # Validate the request body contains JSON
 if request.is_json:
    json_obj = request.get_json()

    eprint("update_SRT_file:  received JSON object: ")
    eprint("Type of received object is", type(json_obj));
 else:
    eprint("update_SRT_file:  Request was not JSON ")
```

Here is what gets printed out:

```
23:12:12.771824 update_SRT_file:  received JSON object: 
23:12:12.771878 Type of received object is **<class 'str'>**
```

Comment: How do you want to store it ?

Comment: My question has to do with how Flask maps a JSON array object.

Comment: Contrary to the answer of @meb Flask should  do the conversion in get_json. The "other" application apparently sends it as json, so the content of the message is probably something else than what you showed as being in the message. That converts to a list when I run it through json.loads.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  Actually, when I print the result I get back from respinse.get_json(), I get the same result as the JSON structure which is included in my post.  The only perform is that Flask is mapping to a string instead of a List.  I also get the correct result if I do a json.loads().  That is what I am using as a workaround.   But to me that seems a "patch" for what appears to be a limitation in Flask.

Comment: I have seen in some threads that Flask does not make it possible to return an array in JSON format.   So what I am seeing might be related to the fact that, in general, Flask does not play well with JSON arrays as an outer structure.

Answer (score 1):

After more investigation, the problem was occuring because the client was JSON encoding the data twice.   Upcon removing the additional encoding, it was found that now Flask correctly maps the incoming JSON Array to a python List structure.

Answer (score 0):

Your POST request is sending the JSON as raw text. Flask then receives it as raw text in the request body. Some web application frameworks might automatically parse the text into a JSON-like object or data structure, but Flask does not, at least not out of the box.

Comment: That is not my understanding.  I am calling the request.get_json() method.  According to the online documentation for this API, this method parses the json.

https://kite.com/python/docs/flask.request.get_json

Also, since the request.isjson is set to true, this means that the MIME type was correctly set to application/json and that Flask has correctly understood that this is a JSON payload, and not just raw text.